# How to add drag n drop functionality in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drag-and-drop, drag

I want to add drag n drop functionality in my app like [Draw.io](http://draw.io) and like trello. Meanz I need fast drag n drop in my app page. But I know how to do it?

Please give me some guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `Draggable` of **Jquery-ui.**

```js
 $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Run the snippet and check.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu2fb20c/)